# Issue with htaccess redirection in WP Multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, 404-error, regex

My site structure is main site `example.com` and two subfolders sites `/es/` and `/en/`

`example.com` redirects => `example.com/es/` and `example.com/en/` is the English version.

What is wrong?

The following:

`example.com/<non-existing-page>` redirects => `example.com/es/`

Some part of this main redirect is causing that every non-existing page inside mysite.com (This site is empty) is redirected to the main page which is in the subdomain `example.com/es/` instead of getting a 404 error. I see where is the problem but I don't know how to modify the rule.

My redirect in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

# Main Redirect

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/es\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/es\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^indexingles\.html$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/en\/" [R=301,L]
```

Works perfect for the following:

1. Is perfect that `example.com/index.php` redirects => `example.com/es`
2. Is perfect that `index.html` redirects => `example.com/es`
3. Is perfect that `indexingles.html` redirects => `example.com/en`

Summarizing

Every URL that has `example.com/<non-existent-page>` redirects to the main page: `example.com/es/`.

It's wrong that a non-existent-page doesn't get a 404 error. I have to change this and I don't know how.

If the URL is `example.com/es/<non-existent-page>` it gets a 404 error which is OK.

If the URL is `example.com/en/<non-existent-page>` it gets a 404 error which is OK.

**Note:**

If somebody else is going to use this redirect, I want to add that Mr. White redirection is working just fine. However order to make the redirection of the backend to work properly I had to delete Wordfence plugin.

Comment: Do you have multiple domain names? Or it is just `example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every URL that has `example.com/<non-existent-page>` redirects to the main page: `example.com/es/`.

This is presumably being done by WordPress itself, as there is nothing in what you've posted (in `.htaccess`) that is doing this.

You probably need to add an additional "wildcard" redirect to redirect `/<anything>` (except for `/es` and `/en`) to `/es/<anything>`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^(es|en)($|/) https://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will naturally encompass the root redirect (your first rule) as well. However, this redirect will need to go after the other two specific redirects that remove `index.html` and `indexingles.html` respectively.

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary to ensure that only direct requests are redirected and not rewritten requests to `index.php` (the WP front-controller). This preventing a redirect loop. The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not set on direct requests but set to "200" (as in "200 OK" HTTP response status) after the first successful rewrite. The alternative would be to include `index.php` in the *alternation* subpattern, however, that wouldn't then canonicalise direct requests to `index.php` itself.

There is no need to backslash escape the slashes, dots and colons in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* since these characters have no special meaning here.

Also, there is no need for the conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) unless you have multiple domains. But even if you are, this can be simplified to a single *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid potential caching issues. And only change to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK. However, language redirects like this should probably be *temporary* anyway.

So, in summary, you should replace your existing redirect directives with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "index.html" and redirect to "/es/"
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ https://example.com/es/ [R=301,L]

# Remove "indexingles.html" and redirect to "/en/"
RewriteRule ^indexingles\.html$ https://example.com/en/ [R=301,L]

# Everything else default to "/es/<anything>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^(es|en)($|/) https://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

> **UPDATE:** What its not working is: `https://example.com/wp-admin/network/` redirected you too many times.

I think you'll probably need to exclude any URL that starts `/wp-admin` (and `/wp-login.php` and `/phpmyadmin`) from the last redirect. Change the last rule to read:

```
# Everything else default to "/es/<anything>"
# With some exceptions...
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^(es|en|wp-admin|wp-login\.php|phpmyadmin)($|/) https://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You could also consider excluding any URL that already maps to a physical file (ie. `-f`). And if more exclusions are required then consider adding additional `RewriteCond` directives instead. For example:

```
# Everything else default to "/es/<anything>"
# With some exceptions...
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(es|en|wp-admin|phpmyadmin)($|/) https://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable includes the slash prefix on the URL-path, but the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not.

Comment: Thanks!! Very grateful for your answer I will test your code in hours with less traffic, and I will came back with the answer.
In the mean time I have a doubt about, what I see in my access log files
It is as follows:
Example:
' 13.66.139.138 - - [29/Jan/2021:18:17:58 +0000] "GET non-existent-file.html HTTP/1.1" 302 613 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http:// www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) X-Middleton/1" '

Bing and other bots are scrolling for files that I don’t have since 8 years ago: Despite the redirect in htaccess file is 301 in the access log is 302.

Comment: @ MrWhite: Do you have multiple domain names? Or it is just example.com?
'example.com' is the only domain in this Multisite

Comment: "Despite the redirect in htaccess file is 301" - you did not have a 301 in your `.htaccess` file for `non-existent-file.html`. (Unless you have other code you have not posted?) The 302 is most probably triggered by WordPress (as I mentioned above). The redirect I posted above will 301 redirect "non-existent-file.html" (assuming that file really does not exist) to `/es/non-existent-file.html`, which you say should generate a 404. However, search engine bots will likely still try and crawl these URLs for many years to come - that is just what they do.

Comment: "'example.com' is the only domain in this Multisite" - in that case, the `RewriteCond` directives that specifically checked the hostname would seem to be superfluous, as I surmised in my answer above. (Assuming you don't have any other subdomains?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. No additional subdomains by now. In Multisite 'example.com' '/es/' and '/en/' are my subdirectory subdomains.

Comment: Sorry but the code provided cause an error of too many redirects

Comment: Ah, the last redirect will conflict with the WordPress front-controller (that rewrites the request to `index.php`). You'll need to add a `RewriteCond` (_condition_) directive to the last rule. I've updated my answer. And make sure you've cleared your browser cache (highlights the importance of first testing with 302 - temporary - redirects).

Comment: Thank you so much you are still helping me. I will try this

Comment: No need to add redirect from www.example.com? My default now is without www. But all the old links are with www. Sorry I did not realize that may be you where asking about this when you ask about other subdomains.

Comment: It does redirect from `www.example.com`. It doesn't explicitly check the hostname, so it will redirect from _any_ host (that resolves to your site) to `example.com`.

Comment: If you mean from `www.example.com/` (the document root) then that is handled by the new redirect (as mentioned above).

Comment: I had edit the code showing what is before the redirect, which already contains, what you last added. ' RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$' Sorry I didn't realized it was part of the redirect.

Comment: Wowwww!!!! Thanks!!! I deleted The three first lines. I put your code and worked! Amazing!!

Comment: What its not working is: https://example.com/wp-admin/network/  redirected you too many times.

Comment: The first two `Header` directives are unrelated to this and might still be required by your site? Yes, that rogue `RewriteCond` directive (3rd line) was incorrect where you had put it. `RewriteCond` directives are _conditions_ that apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. So in my answer above, it applies only to the last rule.

Comment: Is there a fix for the network administrator login?

Comment: I would think you'll need to exclude anything that starts `/wp-admin` from being redirected. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hhmmm, you may have other issues with static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.)? As I suspect these also should not be redirected? Or should they (since you may have language specific resources)?

Comment: I will check but every thing looks fine.  Resources for subsites are separate in wp-content . I cant see nothing wrong by now. I   will check again in the backend

Comment: So far so good thanks! I can access the network and every site dashboard. I have network and subsite plugins, seems to be ok everything.

Comment: That's great. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick/checkmark next to the answer (to help other readers and to remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers that you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi, I still have an issue when trying to access the backend:
I click on: 'http://example.com/wp-admin/network/'
And redirects to: 'https://example.com/es/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsurdelsur.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fnetwork%2F&reauth=1' It appears the login window but when I click nothing happens its freeze. Its supposed not to redirect to /es/. I cleared browser cache and I use Cache Killer extension. Any fix?

Comment: Can't access also  https://example.com/phpmyadmin

Comment: 'example.com/phpmyadmin' this is fixed I added to the exclusion list, but not the login access

Comment: It looks like you need to add an inclusion for `wp-login.php`. I've updated my answer and included some more info.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!!. One more question: if I want to redirect 301 specific old URLs:
 `^/old-directory/.*`
redirects to
`https://example.com/es/new-url`
How should I do that?

Comment: _Aside:_ "an inclusion for wp-login.php" - sorry, that should have read "exclusion", not "inclusion"!

Comment: To redirect specific old URLs you would do it in the same way you are currently redirecting `/index.html` and `/indexingless.html`, before the general redirect at the end. In other words, `RewriteRule ^old-directory/ https://example.com/es/new-url [R=301,L]` - to redirect all URLs that start `/old-directory/` to the specific URL as stated.

Comment: Excellent !!! Thanks!!!